# PHP Comparing an array element to a string to determine results

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
$Output = Array
    (
        [0] => 2013-08-28 13:04:50-05:00
        [1] => 2013-08-28 18:31:29-05:00
        [2] => 2013-08-30 15:08:23-05:00
        [3] => 2013-08-30 21:45:48-05:00
        [4] => 2013-08-31 16:57:50-05:00
    )
```

Now i need to convert each element to a string so I can compare it with these variables:

```
$hr24 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:sP',strtotime("-1 days")));
$hr72 = strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:sP',strtotime("-3 days")));
```

So what I want to do is, if the array element is over 24hr, write it to a TXT file, and if is over 72hr write to a different one. So i have this:

```
$OutputStr = serialize($Output);
$OutputStr = strtotime($OutputStr);

if ($OutputStr > $hr24) {
file_put_contents('/folder/test/test24hr_log.txt', print_r($OutputStr, true));
                    }
    elseif ($OutputStr > $hr72) {
        file_put_contents('/folder/test/test72hr_log.txt', print_r($OutputStr, true));
            }
```

But is not giving me any answer, does anybody have an idea? I dont know if im doing the right comparison for each element. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: `var_dump($OutputStr)`. Then think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hr24 = strtotime("-1 days");
$hr72 = strtotime("-3 days");
$older24 = array();
$older72 = array();
foreach ($Output AS $date) {
  $time = strtotime($date);
  if ($time < $hr72) {
    $older72[] = $date;
  } else if ($time < $hr24) {
    $older24[] = $date;
  }
}
file_put_contents('/folder/test/test24hr_log.txt', serialize($older24));
file_put_contents('/folder/test/test72hr_log.txt', serialize($older72));
```

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/q3r-j5y

Comment: Thanks, I tried your answer, but it seems to be writing all the files on the same TXT file. 
`file_put_contents('/folder/test72hr_log.txt', print_r($Output, true));`

Comment: Thanks, it worked i just have to figure it out how to pass all that data into that TXT, is just taking the last value

Comment: For example, create 2 new arrays for storing these strings. Add each string to appropriate array. After the loop store these arrays to files.

Comment: Yes that's what i thought to do